# How to insert the output of a stored procedure into a table

Tags: mysql

I have a stored procedure with 5 output columns and no arguments. Can you help me with the syntax? In mysql

Comment: Why don't you insert these values right in a stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

You can use prepared statement and use the command :
insert into new_table select * from .....   (whatever your result-set is) within the stored procedure.

Thanks

Comment: can you tell me with an example plz?

Comment: SET @query1 = CONCAT('create table  test_table.daily_report  select col1, col2 from table_in_procedure' );
  PREPARE stmt1 FROM @query1;
     EXECUTE stmt1;

Answer (score 0):

I tried this one and this worked.

```
delimiter //

create procedure proc-name()
begin

insert into table-name

here we have the query for the proc

end //
delimiter ;
```